# "What if you asked him if the sun rise / rose in the east?" Universal truth

Tags: conditional-constructions

Two confusing sentences:

> What if you asked him if he **love / loved** you?
>
> What if you asked him if the sun **rise / rose** in the east? (*universal truth)*

Is there any rule that we should use only **past tense** in case of **2nd conditional?**

Even in case of **universal truth?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JamesK thanks for pointing out the mistake. But which of the sentences is grammartically correct? Please explain.

Comment: The repeated use of the word “believe” makes the writing awkward.  It would be proper to rewrite the sentence to aboud this repetition.

Comment: @whiskeychief ok I'm editing it.

Comment: Grammatically, you should be comparing ***rises*** with *rose* and ***loves*** with *loved*. Without that change, it's forcing a false choice. (Because both *the sun* ***rise*** and *if he* ***love*** are ungrammatical on their own.)